# PHP Parse error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Alright, so this is the code.

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', '*');
define('DB_USERNAME', '*');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*')

$odb = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
?>
```

And it results in:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in * on line 8

I don't see anything wrong there.

So this is the line it's complaining about.

```
$odb = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Help?

Comment: Missing `;` after `define('DB_PASSWORD', '*')`

Comment: Just an unrelated answer... always use `sprintf` to form a string. Here, use `sprintf` the strings inside `new PDO`. 
just a good practice :)

Answer (score 1):

You forget the semicolon ';' in `define('DB_PASSWORD', '*')`;

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', '*');
define('DB_USERNAME', '*');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*');

$odb = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
?>
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `;` semi-colon here

```
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*')
```

It should be,

```
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*');
```

Answer (score 0):

The questions solved but im just leaving some tips:

You should maybe try to read and understand compiler errors a little bit better.

If your compiler tells you a syntax error is in variable 6, you should try to read it carefully.

When it tells you that it "expects" or meets "unexpectes" a certain symbol this means you should read the marked line carefully.

If it tells ya an "unexpected" symbol it means that PHP dont know what the heck this symbol is doing here now, a $ sign (T_VARIABLE) after a closed bracked ")" (function call) makes no sense.

Basically tells you exactly that a ";" is missing.

The compiler often tells you directly whats wrong, its just a matter of learning and understanding this messages as its a matter to learn the programming language itself.